# JBoss/Alfresco cannot write on slave after failover

Tags: mysql, replication, high-availability, failover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JBoss don't fail over MySQL slave using datasource](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19453/jboss-dont-fail-over-mysql-slave-using-datasource)

I'm trying to set up an **high available MySQL "cluster"**, using a **Master / Slave Replication configuration**. I want to the slave become master (e.g. not read-only but writeable) if the first node come down (like in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409111/database-fail-over-in-jboss-data-sources or in my previous question ).

**But I am unable to specify to MySQL (or JBoss) to use slave in read-write mode.**

The doc says : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

> Failover Support
>
> MySQL Connector/J has failover support. This enables the driver to fail over to any number of slave hosts and still perform read-only queries. Failover only happens when the connection is in an autoCommit(true) state, because failover cannot happen reliably when a transaction is in progress. Most application servers and connection pools set autoCommit to true at the end of every transaction/connection use.
>
> The failover functionality has the following behavior:
>
> ```
>   If the URL property autoReconnect is false: Failover only happens at connection initialization, and failback occurs when the driver determines that the first host has become available again.
>
>   If the URL property autoReconnect is true: Failover happens when the driver determines that the connection has failed (checked before every query), and falls back to the first host when it determines that the host has become available again (after queriesBeforeRetryMaster queries have been issued).
> ```
>
> **In either case, whenever you are connected to a “failed-over” server, the connection is set to read-only state, so queries that attempt to modify data will throw exceptions (the query will never be processed by the MySQL server).**

So, is there any way of failing over the slave in a WRITE mode ? In all threads I have read,  this sounds possible, particularly specifying

false

But it don't seems to work :(.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

---

***Datasource configuration***

```xml
<datasources>

    <local-tx-datasource>
        <jndi-name>alfresco-datasource</jndi-name>
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://10.1.2.13,10.1.2.14:3306/alfresco
        </connection-url>
        <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
        <user-name>alfresco</user-name>
        <password>alfresco</password>
        <exception-sorter-class-name>
            org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter
        </exception-sorter-class-name>

        <!-- Infique que le failover est accessible en ecriture -->
        <connection-property name="readOnly">false
        </connection-property>
        <failOverReadOnly>false</failOverReadOnly>
        <autoReconnect>true</autoReconnect>
        <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>

        <metadata>
            <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
        </metadata>
    </local-tx-datasource>

</datasources>
```

---

***MySQL Configuration***

Here my MySQL configuration files (in case I forgot something) :

Master (10.1.2.13)

```
[mysqld]
user            = s-mysql
port            = 3306
basedir         =/app/mysql/current
datadir         =/app/data/mysql
log-error       =/app/log/mysql/master
log             =/app/log/mysql/query.log

#clustering
server_id       =1
log-bin         =/app/log/mysql/log-bin/log-bin.master
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog     =1
skip-slave-start
expire_logs_days=10

binlog-do-db    =alfresco
```

Slave (10.1.2.14)

```
[mysqld]
user            = s-mysql
port            = 3306
basedir         =/app/mysql/current
datadir         =/app/data/mysql
log-error       =/app/log/mysql/slave
log             =/app/log/mysql/query.log

# Clustering
server_id       =2
log-bin         =/app/log/mysql/log-bin/log-bin.slave
expire_logs_days=10
skip-slave-start
relay-log-index =/app/log/mysql/log-relay/relay-log.slave.index
relay-log       =/app/log/mysql/log-relay/relay-log.slave

binlog-do-db    =alfresco
replicate-do-db =alfresco
```

Slave privileges

```
SHOW GRANTS for 'alfresco'@'10.1.2.11';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for alfresco@10.1.2.11                                                                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'alfresco'@'10.1.2.11' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD     '*F9F457310EF9364D42AABE6D8C24A21712C000B5' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `alfresco`.* TO 'alfresco'@'10.1.2.11' WITH GRANT OPTION                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

***Tests and results***

In order to test my configuration, I just stop the first instance :

```shell
service mysql stop
```

But I'm facing what I was fearing :

```
### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed
; SQL []; Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection is read-only. Queries leading to data modification are not allowed
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:107)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:71)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:346)
```

Could someone give me hints, for solving this issue please ?

Comment: Jean-Remy,  you can edit this post to reflect your new requirements.   A Closed post is not locked and can still be edited.  There is also no reason you can't open a new question on your new requirements, which is what I would recommend.