# JBoss don't fail over MySQL slave using datasource

Tags: mysql, high-availability, failover

I'm trying to set up an high available MySQL cluster, using a Master / Slave configuration. I want to the slave become master (e.g. not read-only but writeable) if the first node come down (like in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409111/database-fail-over-in-jboss-data-sources)

So, I'm using a datasource with Connector/J drivers :

```xml
<datasources>

    <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>alfresco-datasource</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://10.1.2.13,10.1.2.14:3306/alfresco</connection-url>
    <driver-class>org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>alfresco</user-name>
    <password>alfresco</password>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>
        org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter
    </exception-sorter-class-name>


    <connection-property name="readOnly">false</connection-property>
    <failOverReadOnly>false</failOverReadOnly>

    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>

    <metadata>
      <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

I read many many post here  dealing about this, but I'm not yet sure this is sufficient (indeed I'm sure it's not ;)).

In order to test my configuration, I just stop the first instance :

```shell
service mysql stop
```

As soon as my application (Alfresco, relying on Activiti), which is using Ibatis, detect there is a failure, it's flooding me of message saying that connection is lost / refused,  .... So the fail over don't work.

```
    GRAVE: Error while closing command context
    org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
    ### Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet successfully received from the server was 1 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    ### The error may exist in org/activiti/db/mapping/entity/Job.xml
    ### The error may involve org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobEntity.selectNextJobsToExecute_mysql
    ### The error occurred while executing a query
    ### SQL: select *      from ACT_RU_JOB      where (RETRIES_ > 0)       and (DUEDATE_ is null or DUEDATE_ <= ?)       and (LOCK_OWNER_ is null or LOCK_EXP_TIME_ <= ?)
    ### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet successfully received from the server was 1 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
        at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:8)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:77)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.db.DbSqlSession.selectList(DbSqlSession.java:191)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.JobManager.findNextJobsToExecute(JobManager.java:97)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.AcquireJobsCmd.execute(AcquireJobsCmd.java:49)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.AcquireJobsCmd.execute(AcquireJobsCmd.java:32)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:24)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:42)
        at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:42)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
        at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:40)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:33)
        at org.activiti.engine.impl.jobexecutor.JobAcquisitionThread.run(JobAcquisitionThread.java:63)
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure


[...]


Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2552)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3002)
    ... 45 more
09:54:00,270 WARN  [LocalManagedConnectionFactory] Destroying connection that is not valid, due to the following exception: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4LoadBalancedMySQLConnection@33dd0edd
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 31 875 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.

[...]

09:54:00,355 WARN  [JBossManagedConnectionPool] Destroying connection that could not be successfully matched: org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$TxConnectionEventListener@34775a91[state=DESTROYED mc=org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@244f22a3 handles=0 lastUse=1339055604851 permit=false trackByTx=false mcp=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$OnePool@3d01c1a context=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool@53e4f0ea xaResource=org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$LocalXAResource@476b0df4 txSync=null]
09:54:01,702 ERROR [STDERR] Thu Jun 07 09:54:01 CEST 2012 WARN: Connection to primary host failed

EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:



** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

And so on ...

I had problem before, because my app server user (alfresco@10.1.2.11) wasn't granted on the databsase. But it's resolved for now.

Here my MySQL configuration files (in case I forgot something) :

Master (10.1.2.13)
        [mysqld]
    user            = s-mysql
    port            = 3306
    basedir         =/app/mysql/current
    datadir         =/app/data/mysql
    log-error       =/app/log/mysql/master
    log             =/app/log/mysql/query.log

```
#clustering
server_id       =1
log-bin         =/app/log/mysql/log-bin/log-bin.master
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog     =1
skip-slave-start
expire_logs_days=10

binlog-do-db    =alfresco
```

Slave (10.1.2.14)

```
[mysqld]
user            = s-mysql
port            = 3306
basedir         =/app/mysql/current
datadir         =/app/data/mysql
log-error       =/app/log/mysql/slave
log             =/app/log/mysql/query.log

# Clustering
server_id       =2
log-bin         =/app/log/mysql/log-bin/log-bin.slave
expire_logs_days=10
skip-slave-start
relay-log-index =/app/log/mysql/log-relay/relay-log.slave.index
relay-log       =/app/log/mysql/log-relay/relay-log.slave

binlog-do-db    =alfresco
replicate-do-db =alfresco
```

Slave privileges

```
SHOW GRANTS for 'alfresco'@'10.1.2.11';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for alfresco@10.1.2.11                                                                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'alfresco'@'10.1.2.11' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD     '*F9F457310EF9364D42AABE6D8C24A21712C000B5' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `alfresco`.* TO 'alfresco'@'10.1.2.11' WITH GRANT OPTION                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Could someone give me hints, for solving this issue please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it seems that I "forgot" one parameter

```xml
<autoReconnect>true</autoReconnect>
```

I said forgot with precaution, because as the per doc says : https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SetUpAMysqlDatasource

> Automatic reconnect
>
> WARNING: DO NOT ENABLE AUTO RECONNECT IF YOU ARE USING MANAGED TRANSACTIONS
>
> The auto reconnect does not preserve transaction state in the database.
>
> It is ok if you are ALWAYS using auto-commit=true.

I wasn't sure that I could activate it ... and I'm still questionning.

***EDIT***
SPLIT thread, because my first question is (auto)answered.
I will add some information about Alfresco, auto commit and managed transaction if I get some.

read-write mode issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945261/jboss-alfresco-cannot-write-on-slave-after-failover